# how to bypass PATHINFO_EXTENSION

Tags: php

I'm doing pentest work and I came across the code below, how can I bypass this concatenation of the file so that at the end it has ".php" and not newnamephp

```
function show($uploaddir,$urlrepositorio,$subdir,$root, $width){
        $novoid="resized".time ();

        $path = $_FILES['url']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $novonome=$novoid.$ext;
        
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($novonome);

        $url_atual = "//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;
        $pos = strripos($url_atual, '/');
        $rest = substr($url_atual, 0, $pos); 

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            geraVisualizacao($root,$subdir,$novonome,$novoid, $width);
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
}
```

bypass PATHINFO_EXTENSION

Comment: change  `$novonome=$novoid.$ext;` to   `$novonome=$novoid.".".$ext;`

Comment: I can't modify the php file, I can only upload files to the server

Comment: To bypass the given code:

Name your malicious file malicious.php.php.
When the code processes the filename, the pathinfo function will return php as the extension.
The new name of the file will be resized[TIMESTAMP].php.

Comment: I tried to do this previously, but the file name remains "resized[TIMESTAMP]php" and this means that the server does not actually interpret it as a valid php file

Comment: I don't think it's possible looking at this  code

Answer (score 0):

To get **PATHINFO_FILENAME** and **PATHINFO_EXTENSION** *pathinfo()* splits the string at the position of the very last . (dot). This means, no matter what the filename is, **PATHINFO_EXTENSION** can never contain any dots, not at the beginning nor anywhere else.

If filename has multiple occurrences of . (dot), all but the last one (which will be omitted) will be returned as part of **PATHINFO_FILENAME**.